# How to insert data In Many to Many related table pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

[image]

I have Folder table Has many Tasks and any task has many todos i need to insert array of  tasks and each task has many todos

In my controller i insert folder tasks but how i can insert todos in each task

```
  $newFolder = $this->folder::create($this->folder->toArray());
                if($newFolder){
                    $newFolder->missions()->sync($this->selectedMissions);
                    $newFolder->tasks()->sync($this->selectedTsks);
                }
```

In Folder Model i create this relation Todo is pivot modal `extends Pivot`

```
 // relations
    public function tasks(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class,'folder_tasks','folder_id','task_id')->using(Todo::class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? And is the code when you're creating a new folder correct? It says `$this->selectedTsks`.

Comment: Yes the code of creating folder is correct but the problem is after sync folder tasks in need to insert todos also todos is related table pivot 
`$newFolder->tasks()->sync($this->selectedTsks);`

Comment: Do you have a part that isn't working specifically? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Acutely i don't have some code not work or bugs but i need solution , best way to insert todos to every task

Comment: Would something like `$newFolder->tasks->each->todos()->sync($todos)` work for you? Just loop through all the tasks and sync the todos for that task.

Comment: Thank you ,i will try with this way